# Comment trouver toutes les expansions d'un groupe ?

Tags: grammaire

J'ai un devoir dans lequel je dois trouver toutes les expansions des groupes de mots sélectionnés. Le professeur indique qu'il y a 15 expansions au total, et j'en ai trouvé que 12.

**Analyse grammaticale 8**

**Relevez les expansions des mots soulignés dans le texte suivant et indiquez la nature et la fonction de ces expansions. Il y a 15 expansions en tout.**

> La science
>   C’est à partir du XVIIe siècle que la science a vraiment posé les jalons de la modernité. Les Newton, Descartes et autres érudits ont été **amenés**(1), par leurs découvertes diversifiées, à révolutionner le monde scientifique. Bien sûr, d’autres avant eux s’étaient aventurés sur le chemin de la connaissance. Copernic et Galilée, pour ne nommer que ces deux-là, avaient osé défier l’Église catholique en affirmant, entre autres, que la Terre tournait autour du Soleil, et non l’inverse comme l’auraient souhaité les théologiens. Condamnés pour hérésie, ces **hommes**(2) ont été les **victimes**(3) toutes désignées de **l’époque**(4) obscure à laquelle ils appartenaient. Quant à Galilée, il a dû renier la théorie dument **confirmée**(5) par ses recherches. Sinon, il aurait été aussitôt la **proie**(6) d’un bucher allumé par les bien-pensants qui niaient toute preuve, même irréfutable, si celle-ci remettait en question les enseignements décrétés par le clergé.
>
> Aujourd’hui, la situation est tout autre pour les savants, qui se voient respectés par leurs pairs et par la société en général. Qu’ils soient récipiendaires d’un prix Nobel ou simples **chercheurs**(7) universitaires œuvrant dans l’ombre, ils sont conscients de l’intérêt et des espoirs qu’ils suscitent. Installés aux premières loges du spectacle de l’humanité, ils en **sont**(8) les fidèles interprètes.

voici les réponses que j'ai trouvées

- amenés

  - à révolutionner le monde scientifique (gprep, CI)
  - par leurs diversifiées(gprep, CI)
- hommes

  - Condamnés pour hérésie (GAdj, CN)
- victimes

  - toutes désignées *de l’époque obscure à laquelle ils appartenaient* ?? (GAdj, CN)
- l'époque

  - obscure (gadj, cn)
  - à laquelle ils appartenaient(sub rel, cn)??
- confirmée

  - dument (gadv, mod v)
  - par ses recherches(gprep ,ci)
- proie

  - d’un bucher allumé par les bien-pensants  (gprep, cn)
- chercheurs

  - simples (gadj, cn)
  - universitaires œuvrant dans l’ombre (gadj, cn)
- sont

  - les fidèles interprètes. (gadj, cd)

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble qu'il manque

- ont été amenés
- ces hommes
- la proie

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ta réponse.

Comment: Tu peux étendre « amené » à « ont été amenés ».

Comment: donc tu me dis que ont été amenés est une expansion de amenés ?

Answer (score 1):

Je sais peu des termes d'analyse grammaticale utilisés par les linguistes francophones, lesquels sont aussi peu connus pour moi, mais je crois que ce soit le piège du système multicouche, c'est-à-dire, le mot "hommes" contient le mot "victimes" comme un prédicat nominal, ceci, à son tour, contenant un déterminant du participe passé avec un quantifieur expressif "toutes désignées", et puis il y a un  déterminant nominal "de l’époque". Donc, le système sera

[[[[hommes]]] ont été les [[[victimes]] toutes désignées]] de l’époque]